# How does the comapareTo method in Java works?

Tags: java, compareto

Can anyone explain how does the following codes works?

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Item) {
        return date1.compareTo( ((Item) o).getDate2());
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Its impossible to explain the code without knowing what `getDate2()` returns.

Comment: The code does exactly what it does.  There's no way to explain *why* the code does that without seeing a broader context.  By its self, that method looks a little odd.

Comment: Can not explain without more code . At least , the definition of date1 and getDate2() .

Comment: Do not use Stack Overflow when you could read the appropriate documentation. We do not explain *how code works*, we help you *solve programming problems*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It check that object o is an item, then compares them, the compare to function returns the values, -1, 0 and 1.

If it returns a value of 0 it means the objects are the same, if it return -1  or 1 it is saying that they are not the same.

The return at the end is the default catch, so if object o is not of that item type return no match.